# Haskell -- Unexpected expected type

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, infinite

I'm trying to write a function in Haskell that will pop some items that have been serialized to a list of strings. (This list represents the lines of a text file -- one line is not necessarily one item)

The function is called with another function as a parameter. This function will pop a single item off, and return a tuple containing that item and the remainder of the text. The function is supposed to recursively perform this operation n times, each time adding the result a list. It returns this list along with the remainder of the text, to be used for further parsing.

```
popN :: Integer -> [String] -> ([String]-> (a, [String])) -> ([a], [String])
popN n txt fun  | n == 0 = ([], txt)
                | n /= 0 = do
                    let (tp, newtxt) = fun txt
                    let newnum = n - 1
                    let (rest, after) = popN newnum newtxt fun
                    return (tp : rest, after)
```

When I attempt to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match the expected type '[String]' with actual type '([a], [String])'
In the first argument  of 'return', namely '(tp : rest, after)'
```

The actual type, `([a], [String])` is the type I would expect. What I don't understand, however, is why `[String]` is the expected type. Could someone explain to me why GHC expects this function to return a `[String]`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The `do` notation implies that your return type is a monad, such as `[a]`, `IO a`, `Maybe a`, etc.  Tuples, by themselves, do not form a monad, so you can't use the `do` notation or `return` with them.

Comment: Great question title!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` takes a value of type `t` and produces a value of type `m t` where `m` is some monad. The result of your function is the result of applying `return` to an argument. So which type must that argument have if the result is to be of type `([a], String)`? Well, the only way that `return x` could produce a value of type `([a], String)` would be if `x` had type `[String]` and `m` was the type constructor `(,) [a]` (not taking into account, at that point, that presumably no such instance exists in the prelude). Therefore the type checker expects the argument to be a `[String]`.

Answer (score 0):

`do` is for monadic functions, but yours is pure:

```
popN :: Integer -> [String] -> ([String]-> (a, [String])) -> ([a], [String])
popN 0 txt _ = ([], txt)
popN n txt fun = (a:as, txt'') where
    (a, txt') = fun txt
    (as, txt'') = popN (n-1) txt' fun
```

It does appear that `txt` is acting as state that is threaded through the function, and could be hidden by using the `State` monad.

```
type S = State [String]

popN :: Integer -> S a -> S [a]
popN 0 _ = return []
popN n m = do
    a <- m
    as <- popN (n-1) m
    return (a:as)
```

But this is basically `replicateM` (if you can deal with `Int` instead of `Integer`).

Comment: While that's true (though GHC does not actually care), the problem here is really the `return` - much more so than the `do`.

Comment: @sepp2k good point, there wasn't really any `>>=` in the original `do` block.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you cannot use monads because the tuple that you are returning is not a monad. You can use simple recursion like so:

```
popN :: Integer -> [String] -> ([String]-> (a, [String])) -> ([a], [String])
popN 0 txt _    = ([], txt)
popN n []  _    = ([], [])
popN n txt fun  = (tp:rest, newtxt1)
    where
        (tp,   newtxt ) = fun txt
        (rest, newtxt1) = popN (n-1) newtxt fun
```